# Getting Error: 400 Bad request! what could be the fix?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

**API Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]

public string FetchPayeeDetails(string strDetails)
    {
        
        try
        {
            // PayeeDetails is a class
            PayeeDetails objDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayeeDetails>(strDetails);
            string AccNo = objDetails.AccNo;
            string ChequeNo = objDetails.ChequeNo;
            string Amount = objDetails.Amount;

       // rest of the code

            return "something";          // string is returned
         }
        catch(Exception ex){
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

**Ajax Call Code**

```
    var Ac = $('#AccNo').val();
    var Ch = $('#ChequeNo').val();
    var Am = $('#Amount').val();
    var API_URI = "http://IP:Port/api/contollerName"
    var objData = {};
    
    objData.AccNo = Ac;
    objData.ChequeNo = Ch;
    objData.Amount = Am;
     
    $.ajax({
        url: API_URI,
        type: "POST",
        data: {strDetails:JSON.stringify(objData)},
        
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json;",
        mode: 'cors',
        success: function (Data) {
            
            $('#PayeeName').val(Data);
            
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           
           $('#PayeeName').val("Error at Ajax!");
        }
    });
```

**Error at Ajax:**

```
Console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

responseJSON: {type: 'https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1', title: 'One or more validation errors occurred.', status: 400, traceId: '00-35e7f6bbc2a7d7952564f2644721eaa9-fa7b6123403222bf-00', errors: {…}}

responseText: "{\"type\":\"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1\",\"title\":\"One or more validation errors occurred.\",\"status\":400,\"traceId\":\"00-35e7f6bbc2a7d7952564f2644721eaa9-fa7b6123403222bf-00\",\"errors\":{\"strDetails\":[\"The strDetails field is required.\"]}}"
```

Comment: `contentType: "application/json;",`, it means the data format you send to server is json format, so you can comment this line, then check again.

Comment: @JasonPan contentType: "application/json;",already tried without this..but getting the same error

Comment: The code you provided can't reproduce the issue, 
please create a simplified code that can reproduce the problem. For .net core project, it is enough to provide cshtml, controller, startup.cs or program.cs(.net 6).